# Why doesn't my request.user have groups in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions, authorization

I've got an endpoint built with Django Rest Framework, to which I now want to add permissions so that only users belonging to a certain group can access an endpoint. So I'm using token based access and inspired by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59947593/1650012) I'm trying to use the following code:

```
class ReadPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.groups.filter(name=settings.GROUP_POST_DATA).exists()

class MyEndpoint(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ReadPermission]
    http_method_names = ['get']
    # etc
```

But unfortunately I get an`AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'groups'`

Why doesn't the user object have groups?

Comment: Can you show the authentication class you are using if it is custom? It could be that the user object attached to the request isn't the right one

Comment: Can you add the versions of Django and Django REST Framework?

Comment: Your code fragment is correct; can you show the registration of MyEndpoint (in urls.py) ?
I would also insert a breakpont (pdb.set_trace() is OK) in ReadPermission .has_permission() and inspect "request.user". Is it a User ? 
Then try "dir(request.user)" to show the attributes of the object. Is "groups" present ?
And finally: request.user.groups.all(). Can you see a queryset of groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you're not using or inheriting from the default Django `User` model (or the `AbstractUser`) from `django.contrib.auth.models`, which have the ManyToMany relationship to `Groups`.

If you're using some custom `User` model you can simply add the `PermissionsMixin` from the aforementioned module to inheritance ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions)). And also make sure that `django.contrib.auth` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I don't define a custom user model. Also, I added `django.contrib.auth` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`. I added a breakpoint to the view to inspect the element. Would you have any idea how I can inspect it from pdb to check whether it has the many to many relationships?

Answer (score 2):

The issue must be in you [**`authentication_classes`**--(DRF doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#authentication_classes) attribute (or [**`DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`** settings -- (DRF doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/))

Behind the scenes, the DRF authentication classes fetch the *auth user* from the database and assign it to the `request` object only after the ***specified request entity*** (like *Token*, `JWT Token`, `CSRF Token`, etc) validated against the database. This validation and assigning process is happening in the ***authentication classes***.

Suppose, if Django or DRF failed to identify the requested user, it will assign the [**`AnonymousUser`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object) object to the `request`.

Fortunately, the **`AnonymousUser`** object does have a **`groups`** and **`user_permissions`** attributes. Which means, neither **`request.user.groups`** nor **`request.user.user_permissions`** will not raise any ***`AttributeError`*** exceptions.

Coming to your case, the `request.user.groups` raised an exception, which indicates

1. the received `User` object is neither [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) nor [**`AnonymousUser`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object)
2. the `MyEndpoint` is missing a `authentication_classes` attributes, hence DRF uses the **`DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`**, which may contain a ***custom class, which may not built properly***

### Solution

I assume you need to use the token-based auth system, so I am using the [DRF's **`TokenAuthentication`** -- (DRF doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) here.

Assigning **`authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)`** in the view class will definitely sets the **`request.user`** to either `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` instance or `AnonymousUser`.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication


class MyEndpoint(
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ReadPermission]
    http_method_names = ['get']
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

#### Note

The issue does not belong to the `permission_classes` settings, but the **`authentication_classes`**

---

**Still not solved??**

1. Is it reproducible? (your code snippet is working nicely in my machine, probably everyone's machine) If so, add the steps to reproduce
2. What is the value of [**`MIDDLEWARE`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE)? Do you have any custom one?
3. What is the value of [**`UNAUTHENTICATED_USER`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#unauthenticated_user)?